# Google Maps having directions doesn't work on mobile : "No Routes Found"

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I wanted to have a **map having directions** set to a static destination.

From what i saw, i gave a link as follows:

```
<a href="https://www.google.com/maps?saddr=My+Location&daddr=760+West+Genesee+Street+Syracuse+NY+13204" target="_blank">link</a>
```

Which opens up a new page with the map.

I **haven't been able** to replicate this on mobile (Android/Ios) however.
Following error comes up on the mobile: *"No Routes Found"* .

Can you explain me what am doing wrong?

PS: Am currently using this on a responsive website adding it as a link. I don't want this embedded either.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing the URL like the below one. It might help you.

```
http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=Current+Location&daddr=Kochi+Kerala+India
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The query string format is an older format, so maybe this newer syntax might work:

```
<a href="https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Current+Location/760+West+Genesee+Street+Syracuse+NY+13204" target="_blank">link</a>
```

I've found that sometimes Google likes different phrasings for the current location, so if that doesn't work, you could also try something like `Your+Location`.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot not use coordinates as source address because I send out a link in an email and my clients can be anywhere in the city when they read it.

For me neither of "My+Location" nor "Current+Location" worked. It always set the **source address** to the official center coordinates of the current city or the official address of the internet provider. Both on mobile or in desktop browser.
Christian explained here why: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59249673/5356216

The recommended and working solution in 2022 which is language independent is this:

```
https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&destination=760+West+Genesee+Street+Syracuse+NY+13204
```