# Gmaps - Current position mobile multilingal

Tags: google-maps

On my website, I'm using web URL's to get directions from the current location of the user to a specific location.

The link used is this :

```
https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Current+Location
```

On my mobile which is in English, it works pretty well.
But, on the mobile of my girlfriend, which is in French, the `'Current+Location'` is not recognized and sends an error.

Is there a common denomination for Current+Location which work in all languages?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the current location is only working with the English locale set up. Like the [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15042283/current-location-google-maps-link-to-directions) here by Jon Alslund-Lanthén. I am not sure if this will work, but you can try to use the Google Maps Specific with the country France and check if you can query the current location `"https://www.google.fr/maps/dir///@46.75984,1.738281,6z?hl=fr"`