# Embedding a google map that uses "my location"

Tags: html, google-maps, iframe, location, embed

I want the users of my webpage to be able to see an embedded google map with directions from their location to my address.

The following link correctly gets a users location and get the directions to London Bridge.

www.google.co.uk/maps?saddr=my%20location&daddr=london%20bridge

If I use google to get an embed link for that page the start address becomes static. So the embedded map wouldn't get the users location it would just use mine from when I created it.

Swapping the embed source from google with the above link results in a "could not be found" error.

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.co.uk/maps?saddr=my+location&daddr=london+bridge" width="600" height="450" style="border: 0;" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>

<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m26!1m12!1m3!1d158597.88842955438!2d-0.5380009862678417!3d51.60320274241831!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!4m11!3e6!4m3!3m2!1d51.704112699999996!2d-0.7091171!4m5!1s0x4876035159bb13c5%3A0xa61e28267c3563ac!2sLondon+Bridge%2C+London+SE1+9DD!3m2!1d51.5078788!2d-0.0877321!5e0!3m2!1sen!2suk!4v1485450192422" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Attempting to modify the embed code from google also results in a blank world google map.

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?saddr=my%20location&daddr=london%20bridge" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22330384/4398840), it has all resources you need.